# Gemfire Local Caching Expiration

Tags: java, caching, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I have a JAR that embedded within a webservice that has local Gemfire Caching. The problem that I am trying to solve is expiration of this data.

I have created a custom expiration timer that will set each entries expiration in seconds and have tied a listener to check for afterInvalidate(EntryEvent e).

Here is my region declaration in spring

```
<bean id="rse-region" class="org.springframework.data.gemfire.RegionFactoryBean"
          p:name="rse-region" p:cache-ref="gemfire-cache-embedded">
        <property name="cacheListeners">
            <array>
                <bean class="CustomListener"/>
            </array>
        </property>
        <property name="attributes">
            <bean class="org.springframework.data.gemfire.RegionAttributesFactoryBean"
                  p:enableGateway="false"
                  p:statisticsEnabled="true"
                  p:dataPolicy="NORMAL"
                  p:customEntryTimeToLive-ref="customExpiration">
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

What I am trying to do is a bit different than how I have setup. What I am trying to do is once the initial entry is put into the region I want a Time to Live on that region. Is it possible to do Time to Live on a local gemfire region?

Answer (score 1):

It is. Spring Data GemFire provides  for region time-to-live.